# finding maximum length of upper envolope

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am solving a spoj problem  [**Rectangles Perimeter**](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MMAXPER)  
the problem is

Given  are n  rectangles,  numbered  from 1  to n. We place  them tightly on  the  axis OX,  from  left  to right, according to 
rectangles' numbers. Each rectangle stays on the axis OX either by its 
shorter or by its longer side (see the picture below). Compute the 
length of the upper envelop line, i.e. perimeter's length of the obtained 
figure minus  the  length of  the  left, right and 
bottom straight line segments of the picture. Write program to 
find the maximum possible length of the upper envelop line.

for example

[image]

A configuration, that yields the maximum length of the upper envelop
line, is presented on the picture. 
The  upper  envelop  line  consists  of  segments DC, CG, GF, FJ,  JI,  IM,
ML, LP,  and PO. 
The  total length is 5 + 6 + 3 + 7 + 10 + 13 + 7 + 12 + 5 = 68

input is

> On  the  first  line  of  the  standard  input,  the  value  of  n  is
>   written. On  each  of  the  next  n  lines,  two integers are given  –
>   a_i  and b_i – the side lengths of the i_th rectangle.   Constraints: 
>   0 < n < 1000; 0 < a_i < b_i < 1000, for each i = 1, 2, …, n.

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
5 
2 5 
3 8 
1 10 
7 14 
2 5
```

output is

On a line of the standard output, your program should write the 
result as a positive integer

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
68
```

I am using a using an approach where I fix rectangles one by one and find the maximum length of upper envelop then use that ans to find the next maximum length of envelop and so on..

my code is ...

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <stack>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

typedef double dbl;
typedef float flt;
typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vvi;
typedef pair<ll,int> pli;


#define eps 1e-9
#define inf 1000000000
#define infll 1000000000000000000LL
#define abs(x) ((x)<0?-(x):(x))
#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))
#define pb push_back
#define mp make_pair
#define fi first
#define se second
#define sz(x) ((int)(x).size())
#define FORab(i,a,b) for (int i=(a); i<=(b); ++i)
#define RFORab(i,a,b) for (int i=(a); i>=(b); --i)
#define FOR1(i,n) FORab(i,1,(n))
#define RFOR1(i,n) RFORab(i,(n),1)
#define FOR(i,n) FORab(i,0,(n)-1)
#define RFOR(i,n) RFORab(i,(n)-1,0)
#define allstl(i,x,t) for (t::iterator i = (x).begin(); i!=(x).end(); ++i)
#define rallstl(i,x,t) for (t::reverse_iterator i = (x).rbegin(); i!=(x).rend(); ++i)
#define ms(a,v) memset(a,v,sizeof(a))
#define msn(a,v,n) memset(a,v,n*sizeof(a[0]))
#define mcp(d,s,n) memcpy(d,s,n*sizeof(s[0]))

template<class T> inline void checkmin(T &a,T b){if(b<a) a=b;}
template<class T> inline void checkmax(T &a,T b){if(b>a) a=b;}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int e1=0,e2=0,e3=0;
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    cin>>n;
    FOR(i,n)
    {
        int l,b;
        cin>>b>>l;
        if(i==0)
        {
            e1=l;
            e2=b;
            e3=b;
           // cout<<e1<<"\n";
            continue;
        }
        int t1=e1+l+max(abs((b-e2)),abs((b-e3)));
        int t2=e1+b+max(abs((l-e2)),abs((l-e3)));
        if(t1<t2)
        {
            e1=t2;
            e2=l;
            e3=e2;
        }
        else if(t1==t2)
        {
            e1=t1;
            e2=l;
            e3=b;
        }
        else
        {
            e1=t1;
            e2=b;
            e3=e2;
        }
       // cout<<e1<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<e1<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

But I still get a wrong answer I don't understand why I am getting an wrong answer..

Comment: This question needs a test case that leads to a failure.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat what is wrong there with my sollution..

Comment: I have no idea. Going through that much uncommented code with no indication that there's a real problem is a lot to ask.

Comment: To make your code readable to other people, you should write it without macros (you used macros even for loops declarations) and with methods. You could also consider more meaningful variable names.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat that is just a template i use it in each problem..

Comment: Well, if you want to make it more likely that someone will answer your question, then you can (i) cut out the extraneous code (ii) explain better what your code is supposed to do (iii) write a brute force solution, write a generator of small, random examples, and post a small test case where this code and the brute force solution give different output. Right now this question is likely to be placed on hold for a combination of issues that would be addressed by (i) and (iii).

Comment: Please, add a detailed description of your algorithm. However, my guess is that 1)your solution uses some kind of greedy algorithm 2)greedy is not correct here.

Comment: @user2040251 yes i used greedy approach but if it is not correct then what i would have to do??

Comment: @Nitin9791 Use dynamic programming. It is definitely correct here and should be easy to code.

Comment: @user2040251 i have think of it already but didnt understand how i can use dp here any hint please??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely that your get wrong answer because greedy algorithm is not correct(I say very likely just because I don't have a counter example, I'm actually sure that it is not correct).

You can use dynamic programming instead. The state is `(prefix_len, rotated)`, where `prefix_len` is the number of rectangles already processed and `rotated` is a bool value that indicates whether the last rectangle was rotated or not. The value of each state is the maximum length of perimeter.
The base case is a case with only one rectangle(it is trivial). To compute values for other states, you can just iterate over the rectangles from left to right, put them in rotated and not rotated position and choose the best option: make a transition from the state `(prefix_len - 1, False)` or `(prefix_len - 1, True)`, depending on which one gives longer perimeter.
The answer is `max(f(n, False), f(n, True))`.

This algorithm uses `O(n)` time and `O(1)` memory(because you actually need to store only the values for `prefix_len - 1`).

Answer (score 1):

As you pass from left to right, your current algorithm currently appears to choose the orientation for rectangle `i` that maximizes the length of the upper envelope for rectangles 0 through `i`. But take a look at the example. If there were one fewer rectangle, then the best solution would be to orient HKLM turned clockwise. So the optimal orientation of a rectangle depends on more than just the rectangle to its left; it also depends on the rectangle to its right.

One way to solve this problem is through dynamic programming. We can observe that the optimal orientation for a rectangle really only depends on the two rectangles that immediately surround it, so we only need to keep a constant amount of state around. Here's some code.

```
// The upper envelope of rectangles 0 through i - 1 given that we orient i - 1 horizontally
int envelopeHorizontal = 0;
// The upper envelope or rectangles 0 through i - 1 given that we orient i - 1 vertically
int envelopeVertical = 0;

int numRectangles;
std::cin >> numRectangles;

int prevShortSide = 0, prevLongSide = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numRectangles; ++i) {
    int shortSide, longSide;
    std::cin >> shortSide >> longSide;

    if (i == 0) {
        envelopeHorizontal = longSide;
        envelopeVertical = shortSide;
    } else {
        const int newHorizontal = longSide
            + std::max(std::abs(prevLongSide - shortSide) + envelopeVertical,
                       std::abs(prevShortSide - shortSide) + envelopeHorizontal);
        const int newVertical = shortSide
            + std::max(std::abs(prevLongSide - longSide) + envelopeVertical,
                       std::abs(prevShortSide - longSide) + envelopeHorizontal);
        envelopeHorizontal = newHorizontal;
        envelopeVertical = newVertical;
    }
    prevShortSide = shortSide;
    prevLongSide = longSide;
}
std::cout << std::max(envelopeHorizontal, envelopeVertical) << "\n";
```

PS Once you get your code working, I strongly suggest you submit it to [codereview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) -- you seem to have developed some habits that make it quite difficult to understand your code.